# Image aspect ratio changes even with match_aspect set to true in bokeh figure with image_url

Tags: bokeh, python-3.8

I tried to keep the aspect ratio of an online image as is. However, the aspect ratio will change when the browser window is resized. This doesn't happen with `image`, but happens with `image_url`. Is this a feature or a bug? Thanks.
I use the `figure(match_aspect=True)` and need to stretch the layer to occupy the full window `layer = layout(p, sizing_mode='stretch_both')`

[image]

Sample code

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import layout
p = figure(match_aspect=True)
p.image_url(['https://static.bokeh.org/logos/logo.png'],0,0,1,1)
layer = layout(p, sizing_mode='stretch_both')
show(layer)
```

Comment: I would say offhand that this seems like a bug specific to the combination of `match_aspect=True` and "stretch" sizing modes. There should really be a range bounds re-compute if the canvas size changes, and that appears to not be happening. Please post a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) with all this information.

Comment: @bigreddot, thanks for your comment. As I mentioned in the question above, the issue does not exist with `image`. It only concerns the combination of `image_url`, `match_aspect=True` and "stretch" sizing modes.